# Understanding strange return syntax: return(*scriptFunction[x])(arguments);

Tags: c

I know the title for this is horrendous and for this I am sorry; I honestly had no idea how to ask my question as I am not well educated on this matter.  Below there is a small bit of code that my question concerns as I have NO idea what is going on or if it is even valid!  Although, I suspect it is valid.

```
return(*scriptFunction[x])(arguments);
```

From my understanding, you can only return 1 value in C (you can have multiple return statements but that is different and off topic).  What is the above statement actually doing?

Comment: Depending on how far along in learning C you are, that may indeed look foreign. As the answers reveal, the return is returning a pointer to a function. An array of function pointers isn't something you would expect to run across at the beginning level of C programming. So don't beat yourself up if you don't recognize it -- look it up...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's not returning a pointer to function.

Comment: I stand corrected, it is returning the result of the pointer to a function..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code:

```
return(*scriptFunction[x])(arguments);
```

actually *is* only returning one value.

The variable `scriptFunction` will be an array of function pointers<sup>(1)</sup>. You look up element number `x` of that array, and call that function, passing the argument `arguments`. Then the return value from *that* function is what you return to your caller.

Other than the function pointer aspect, it's no different to `return sqrt(42)`.

---

By way of example, the following program demonstrates how this can be done:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Two simple functions which add a fixed value.

int fnPlus3 (int n) { return n + 3; }
int fnPlus7 (int n) { return n + 7; }

// An array holding those two functions.

int (*scriptFunction[])(int) = { fnPlus3, fnPlus7 };

int main (void) {
    // Call first function in array.

    int x = 0;
    printf ("%d\n", (*scriptFunction[x])(100));

    // Then call second one.

    x = 1;
    printf ("%d\n", (*scriptFunction[x])(100));

    return 0;
}
```

Although it *prints* the return value from the function rather than returning it again, it still uses the same *expression* and you can see it calls a different function based on the value of `x`:

```
103
107
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Or some form of equivalent, such as a pointer to an array of function pointers, or a pointer to a single function pointer (assuming `x` is always set to zero in that latter case).

Comment: `scriptFunction` could also be a pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: @Keith, added an addendum to cover that and other (less likely in my opinion but certainly possible as you point out) cases.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `scriptFunction` is an array of pointers to functions. `*scriptfunction[x]` is then the dereferenced pointer to function (the `x`-th one). Finally, `*scriptfunction[x](arguments)` represents the invocation of that function applied to `arguments`, so the result of that function is what's returned in the end.

Side comment: the `*` is not really necessary. A pointer to function does not need to be dereferenced to call the function, i.e. you can use

```
return scriptFunction[x](arguments);
```

instead.

Comment: ...and then the first pair of parens is equally superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems the line `return (*scriptFunction[x])(arguments);` `scriptFunction` is an array of function pointers, and this is simply invoking the function at position indexed by variable `x` and sending `arguments` variable contents as its input.

The return value of this invoked function is what ultimately gets returned.

---

This working example should be useful:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func_a(int i)
{
        cout << "func_a: " << i << endl;
}

void func_b(int i)
{
        cout << "func_b: " << i << endl;
}

int main()
{
        void (*funcs[])(int) = { func_a, func_b };

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                (*funcs[i])(i+1);

        return 0;
}
```

The output is below:

```
➜  /tmp  g++ test.cpp -o test
➜  /tmp  ./test
func_a: 1
func_b: 2
```

---

Also, for future reference, you should consult: [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To everyone!

I appreciate all of the help you guys have given me.  Each and everyone of your examples were value added and extremely helpful.  I am impressed that each of you made the assumption that it was an array of pointers to functions; maybe you can let me in on the secret on how you knew!  That was my fault for not saying so first so I apologize.  Yes, arrays of pointers to functions are not the most crystal clear at this stage...

Once again, thanks everyone!

Comment: *assumption that it was an array of pointers to functions .. how you knew!*  That can be figured out by looking at the table of C operator precedence and the expression. Parentheses have the highest precedence and left to right associativity. So left pair of `()` have to be evaluated first. Within that, `[]` have higher precedence than `unary *`. So `[]` goes first. So we  know scriptFunction is an array. Since the array element is being dereferenced and then `()` applied to it, it is a pointer to function